# Check workings for Strong Induction (Proof by Contradiction)

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I want to prove the following:

> Suppose that $P(n)$ is a statement involving a general positive integer $n$.
>
> Then $P(n)$ is true for all positive integers $n$ if:
>
> i) $P(1)$ is true, and
>
> ii) [$P(n)$ holds for all positive integers $n \le k$] $\Rightarrow$ $P(k+1)$, for all positive integers $k$

**My Attempt**:

First, I note that the axiom is equivalent to:

$\left[ P(1) \text{ and } \left[ P(m) \Rightarrow P(m+1), \text{ for }m\le k\right] \right] \Rightarrow  \forall n P(n)$ where $m,k,n$ are positive integers.

So, suppose for contradiction that $\text{not } \forall n P(n)$ is true.

Therefore, we have $P(n_0)$ is false and $1\lt k \lt n_0$ and $n_0=k+1$. ($n_0$ is the least integer such that $P(n)$ is false)

But, since $P(k)$ is true, then $P(k+1)$ is true too. Therefore, $P(n_0)$ is true too. Hence, a contradiction.

Is my proof correct and complete and is there anything else I can do to improve it?
My workings is base on [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eadamchik/21-127/lectures/induction_1_print.pdf) document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there are saveral *principles* in place here.

*(i)* The principle of *mathematical induction* :

> $[P(0) \land \forall k (P(k) \rightarrow P(k+1))] \rightarrow \forall n P(n)$.

You want to prove a form of

*(ii)* The principle of *strong induction* :

> $\forall k[\forall m(m < k \rightarrow P(m)) \rightarrow P(k)] \rightarrow \forall nP(n)$.

*Strong induction* is provable from *mathematical induction*.

In your prove "by contradiction", you made use of :

> "suppose for contradiction that not $∀nP(n)$ is true, i.e. $P(n_0)$ is false for some $n_0$, where $n_0$ is the least integer such that $P(n)$ is false".

But this is

*(iii)* The *least number principle* :

> $P(x) \rightarrow \exists y[P(y) \land \forall z (z < y \rightarrow \lnot P(z))]$

which is provable from *strong induction*.

Conclusion : you cannot avoid induction to prove it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Since I am trying to prove strong induction, does it mean I cannot use the least number principle as it relies on strong induction?

Comment: @mauna - usually, in Peano arithmetic, *mathematical induction* is the *axiom* and the other principles are proved from it. Thus, if you want to prove *strong induction* you can prove it directly from *math ind* or - as you are trying - from *least number*, but in this case you have to prove also *lest number* from *math induction*.